# jquery each background-image Not Working

Tags: jquery, background-image, each

```
$(".slide li").each(function () {
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(images/slider/" & $(this).attr("id") & ".jpg)");
});
```

not working please help..!

Comment: Please define what "not working" means. Any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `+` to concatenate instead of `&`

```
{
    $(".slide li").each(function () {
      $(this).css("background-image", "url(images/slider/" + $(this).attr("id") + ".jpg)");
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use + instead of &

```
$(".slide li").each(function () {
   $(this).css("background-image", "url(images/slider/" + $(this).attr("id") + ".jpg)");
        });
```